# Spring Boot and Jersey produces ClassNotFound

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jersey

I'm trying to package my Spring Boot App which uses Jersey. When the app is launched during development it has no problems to run, the problem comes when I generate a jar file using

```
mvnw package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
```

Which produces the following error.

> Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied depend
>   ency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig'
>    defined in URL [jar:file:..path/Backend/target/celulascontentas-2.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/tech/aabo/celulascontenta
>   s/config/JerseyConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [tech.aabo.ce
>   lulascontentas.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.File
>   NotFoundException: ..path\Backend\target\celulascontentas-2.0.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes (The system cannot find the path s
>   pecified)

My Jersey Config looks like this:

```
package tech.aabo.celulascontentas.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        packages("tech.aabo.celulascontentas.endpoint");
        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tech.aabo</groupId>
    <artifactId>celulascontentas</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>celulascontentas</name>
    <description>API para celulas contentas</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Extra -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.133</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried various combinations but it always produces the same error. Those anybody now how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Jersey classpath scanning limitations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#jersey-classpath-scanning-limitations)**

> The change to the layout of executable jars means that a limitation in
> Jersey’s classpath scanning now affects executable jar files as well
> as executable war files. To work around the problem, classes that you
> wish to be scanned by Jersey should be packaged in a jar and included
> as a dependency in BOOT-INF/lib. The Spring Boot launcher should then
> be configured to unpack those jars on start up so that Jersey can scan
> their contents.

This is a known problem and there is a open [pull](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/196) request that's not merged yet. I suggest you refer this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1345) which mentions some workarounds.

There are few workarounds

> 1. Configure Boot's Maven plugin to unpack the jars containing that
>    package
> 2. Use the below workaround

```
jersey 1:

import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig;

@Component
public class RestApplication extends DefaultResourceConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestApplication.class);

    public RestApplication() {
        getFeatures().put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", true);
    }

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appCtx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        log.info("Rest classes found:");
        Map<String,Object> beans = appCtx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class);
        for (Object o : beans.values()) {
            log.info(" -> " + o.getClass().getName());
            getSingletons().add(o);
        }
    }

}
and

    @Autowired
    RestApplication restApplication;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jersey() {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        bean.setServlet(new ServletContainer(restApplication));
        bean.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
        bean.setUrlMappings(Arrays.asList("/rest/*"));
        return bean;
    }
jersery2:

import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JerseyConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appCtx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        log.info("Rest classes found:");
        Map<String,Object> beans = appCtx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Path.class);
        for (Object o : beans.values()) {
            log.info(" -> " + o.getClass().getName());
            register(o);
        }
    }

}
```